# Tablesaw: how to get the original rows' index after filter?

Tags: java, tablesaw

How can I retrieve the original rows' index after performing a query on the dataset?

I'am using [JTablesaw](https://jtablesaw.github.io/tablesaw/userguide/filters.html) as a Dataset library in Java, and I'm looking for a way to get the original rows' index after performing a query/filter on it.

E.g. considering this dataset:

```
A,B,C
10,5,3
4,7,2
6,9,1
```

and the below code

```
Table table = Table.read().file("data.csv");
Table result = table.where(rows -> rows.intColumn("A").isGreaterThanOrEqualTo(6));
```

With the result table being:

```
A,B,C
10,5,3
6,9,1
```

How can I get in output the orginal rows index?
E.g.

```
[0,2]
```

Answer (score 1):

Before filtering, you can create an index column using the static method IntColumn.indexColumn() and providing the necessary arguments. For example

```
table.addColumns(IntColumn.indexColumn("Index", table.rowCount(), 0));
```

This creates an index column that starts with 0.

Answer (score 0):

Filtering creates a new `Table` object and lacks the option to pull the rows' indices from the original table.

One solution is to create a method like below to allow some sort of dynamic iteration over the original table in order to obtain the indices:

```
    private List<Integer> collectIndices( Table table, String columnName, int condition ) {
        List<Integer> indices = new ArrayList<>();
        for ( int i = 0; i < table.rowCount(); i++ ) {
            if ( table.row( i ).getInt( columnName ) >= condition ) {
                indices.add( i );
            }
        }
        return indices;
    }
```

`collectIndices( table, "A", 6 );` returns `[0, 2]`